# Dict KeyError arise in for loop but actually no error

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

While I have a list of dictionaries **detected_intersections**, which has 236 items. With code:

```
for i in detected_intersections:
    print(i)
```

it looks like:

[image: sample image]

with code:

```
detected_intersections = detect_intersections()
for i in detected_intersections:
    if 'seq' in i:
       print(i)
```

it looks the same with above:

[image: sample image]

But when I use **del statement** or **pop() method** to remove key **seq** in a for loop, KeyError would arise:

[image: sample image]

[image: sample image]

If using code:

```
for i in detected_intersections:
    if 'seq' in i:
        i.pop('seq')
        print(i)
```

Codes would be compiled successfully, but data lose:

[image: sample image]

I am quite sure about that there is **seq** in every items of list and their case are correct, I am confused that why it happened.

Thank you

Comment: You last image looks correct all those dictionaries do no have 'seq' since you removed it, isnt that what you want?

Comment: @Taylor Yes, I want to remove 'seq' but some data lose in this way, only 169 items left while there are 236 items in the list originally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one one the `dict` does not have a `seq` key, you will have the `KeyError`. You can prevent this by giving a default return value to `pop()`:

```
i.pop("seq", None)
```

Comment: This is feasible, thank you. But I'm still confused about why my previous codes performs like that. Since there is `seq` in every items of list and their case are correct, which could be proved by a if conditional test. But when I use a if statement and `pop` method, some data will lose? Is it iteration problem?

Comment: I don't know what you want to say by "data lose". You are not require to check for "seq" in the dict, you can use `pop()` directly to prevent 2 lookups in the dict.

Comment: Also, `print(i)` before and after the `pop()` to compare where "seq" is not available.